# How to delete all spaces, \n and \r in every word in list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

[Already try split, join and others - its dont remove all spaces, \n and \r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsP1p.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Have you written any code? Are you getting any errors? How do your results differ from your desired output? Please read about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because currently it's not clear *how* you've attempted to use those string methods. Did you forget to assign your results to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple just do as following,

> Create a new list of var

```
newLs = []
```

> for loop to replace \n , \r and space ([strip()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) , [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp))

```
for o in ls:
    newLs.append(str(o).strip())
```

> Finale code

```
ls = ['               \n eadeaffaedad \r' , '       ladlwamcalmca        \n  \r' ,  ]
newLs = []
for o in ls:
    newLs.append(str(o).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').strip())
print(newLs)
# output:  ['eadeaffaedad', 'ladlwamcalmca']
```

Comment: Both `'\n'` and `'\r'` are whitespace characters and are removed by `.strip()`. You can get at this same answer with just `[s.strip() for s in ls]`.